# How to install MySql Connector/C++ in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu, cmake, mysql-connector

I am quite new with C++ and CMake and for this reason I'm having trouble installing the MySql Connector in Ubuntu 16.04. I know that it's probably a simple task but I've tried for one hour without understanding what should I do.

I'm following this [guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-installation-source-cpp.html) but I don't understand how to install it using the CMake file.

Can someone please give me a simpler or more detailed explanation on what I should do?

Thanks!

Comment: Which part are you getting stuck on?

Comment: In the first section "Configuring Connector/C++", i'm trying to understand how to create the CMake file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt install libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

Comment: Seems to be 1.1.7. Do you need the latest version?

Comment: I'm just doing exercises so the last version is not required. But it has to work with c++11.

Comment: Since you would just be using the connector as a shared library and not compiling it, it should be fine with C++11.

Comment: Cool. Mark it as the answer if it works out for you.

Comment: @vincent is there any alternative for Windows?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-installation-binary.html#connector-cpp-installation-binary-windows